# Is programming Windows Phone 7 different from normal .NET programming?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I know that there must be some differences. I have a Silverlight component ([Timeline](http://timeline.codeplex.com/)) and I want to make it work on Windows Phone 7. do I need to make a lot of changes ? I know .NET and Silverlight but I'm new to mobile phones programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Silverlight but a lot of the .Net framework is not available in WinMo (it usually says on the MSDN pages if it's available or not).
You might have to change your app for other reasons though, since it'll have a smaller screen and you have to be careful about battery usage etc.

The following link has a list of differences:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28VS.96%29.aspx

Comment: Do the references to WinMo compatibility of .NET APIs in MSDN really refer to WinMo 7?  I'd have thought that applies only to WinMo 6.5 and earlier, for apps written for the Compact Framework rather than Silverlight.

Comment: @Nestor: Yes, for example, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28VS.96%29.aspx and down at the bottom of the page under `Version Information` you can see the quote *Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.0*

Comment: @Nestor: Though of course, if you start at the .Net 4 version of the page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) you first have to switch to looking at the Silverlight version, but there's a link to that as soon as you get to that page. Might not be completely obvious, but not that hard to find either.

Answer (score 6):

The UI component of the Windows Phone 7 is supposed to be the same as Silverlight 3, so your timelines should work, as long as they worked properly in Silverlight 3.

The differences are in the APIs (phone-specific stuff... accelerometers, location, etc) and the BCL (Base Class Libraries) because Windows Phone 7 uses the .Net Compact Framework, where Silverlight uses its own implementation of the BCL.

These issues, coupled with the smaller screen and usability differences based on the small touch screen, will make it so you can't simply run the same app easily on the phone. You CAN, however, share a lot of your code, including much of your view code, when porting to the phone.